# Exclude resources in Appassembler Maven Plug-In

Tags: java, maven

I have a Java Maven project, where I use a commercial, third-party dependency which I'm not allowed to redistribute. I use [Appassembler Maven Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/index.html) in my project to collect all dependencies and build a startup script.

Now I want to zip the Appassembler `target` folder and send it to a client, including all open source dependencies, but *excluding* the proprietary dependency. How can I configure Appassember to exclude this JAR?

Comment: May be i misunderstand a thing, but appassembler-maven-plugin is not intended to package things it's intention is to create scripts to start java apps. May be you are talking about the `create-repository` goal?

Comment: Absolutely right, khmarbaise. I meant the create-repository goal.

Comment: The best thing is to do the create-repository via appassembler-maven-plugin and create a package via maven-assembly-plugin and exclude the artifacts you don't like to package based on licenses etc.

Comment: OK thanks, I will try that and ask again if I have questions :-).